# angular6 material event emitter not working

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6, angular-event-emitter

I am trying to implement Event Emitter such that when a todo is inserted into the db, it is added to the list of todos. But it does not work. Please find the code below:
The todoinput component(todo.input.html): component which adds a todo to the database

```
import { Component, OnInit, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { Todos } from '../../models/Todos';
import { TodosService } from '../../services/todos.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-todoinput',
  templateUrl: './todoinput.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./todoinput.component.css']
})
export class TodoinputComponent implements OnInit {

  @Output() newTodo: EventEmitter<Todos> = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(private _todosService: TodosService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  addTodo(text) {
    this._todosService.addTodo({
      text: text,
    }).subscribe((todo) => {
      this.newTodo.emit(todo);
    })
  }

}
```

The app.component.html: which holds all the components.

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<app-todoinput (newTodo)="onNewTodo($event)">
</app-todoinput>
<app-todolist>
</app-todolist>
```

The todolist.component.ts: which adds todo to the list of todos

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Todos } from '../../models/Todos';
import { TodosService } from '../../services/todos.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-todolist',
  templateUrl: './todolist.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./todolist.component.css']
})
export class TodolistComponent implements OnInit {

  todos: Todos[]

  constructor(private _todosService: TodosService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._todosService.getTodos().subscribe((todos) => {
      this.todos = todos;
    })
  }

  onNewTodo(todo: Todos) {
    console.log('-- the passed todo --', todo);
    this.todos.unshift(todo);
  }
}
```

It tries to emit a newTodo, when a todo is added to db. But it throws the error below:

```
AppComponent.html:2 ERROR TypeError: _co.onNewTodo is not a function
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (AppComponent.html:2)
    at handleEvent (core.js:10258)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:11351)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:11054)
    at dispatchEvent (core.js:7717)
```

It looks like a correct implementation. Could anyone let me know what am I doing wrong ? Does it not work with Event Emitter ?

Thanks

Comment: Stackblitz please?

Comment: I'd be able to provide a better answer if you provide me with a stackblitz sample. It's hard to understand until then. But the issue is definitely with the place where you've used the function.

Answer (score 1):

According to your example, you've defined this template `<app-todoinput (newTodo)="onNewTodo($event)">` in your `AppComponent`'s HTML. While your `onNewTodo($event)` is a part of `todolist.component.ts`. Thus the error.

What you should be doing instead is, since you want to change data between two sibling components, you should be implementing a service with a `BehaviorSubject`, instead of an `Output` property in the child component.